# CSS Navbar Transition is Smooth on Scroll Down but no Transition at all on Scroll Back Up

Tags: javascript, css, navbar

I am currently working on a website with a navigation bar at the top of the screen that is initially transparent when you first visit the site, but turns into a white bar with black text the moment you start scrolling down. It also shrinks a little. It has a really nice and smooth transition as it changes it's color and shrinks, but when you scroll back to the top of the page, there is no more smooth transition but rather an instant ugly transition. Actually the changing of the color back to transparent seems okay but the resize of the bar lacks the transition. I uploaded a **GIF** so you can see exactly what's the problem.

There is a second problem I would like to ask for. As you can see in the GIF, there is an underline animation on text hover, however, I cannot get it to work on the white navbar. I want that underline to become black, just like the text and shrink with the rest of the navbar.

Here is the GIF:

https://media.giphy.com/media/5jYbvzN9OzaVm3IRE6/giphy.gif

**Also the CSS:**

```
    /* -=-=-=-=-=   FONT IMPLEMENTATION   =-=-=-=-=- */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300|Roboto:100');


/* -=-=-=-=  END FONT IMPLEMENTATION   =-=-=-=- */

html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
}

body {
      font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
      font-weight: lighter;
}

header.index {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: url(../res/images/back.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
      background-size: cover;
}

header.page1 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: url(../res/images/test.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
      background-size: cover;
}

.content {
      width: 94%;
      margin: 4em auto;
      font-size: 20px;
}

.logoimg {
      position: fixed;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      width: 235px;
      height:54px;
      margin: 37px 80px;

       transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}



nav {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 60px;
      transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul {
      line-height: 100px;
      list-style: none;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      overflow: hidden;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: right;
      margin: 0;  
      padding-right: 50px;
      transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}



nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 16px 20px;
       transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 24px;
       transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}



nav ul li a.current{
    font-weight: 600;



}


nav.scrolled{
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 20px;

  line-height: 40px;
   transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

nav.scrolled ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
      color: #000;
      font-size: 20px;

      line-height: 40px;
       transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav.scrolled img{
   width: 180px;
      height:  41px;
      margin: 27px 80px;
      transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}





/* -=-=-=-=-=   MENU ITEM HOVER ANIMATION   =-=-=-=-=- */


.menu a {
      transition: color 0.1s, background-color 0.1s;

}

.menu a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;


    transition: color 0.1s,background-color 0.1s,padding 0.2s ease-in;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 24px;
    left: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    transform-origin: right top;
    transform: scale(0, 1);
    transition: color 0.1s,transform 0.2s ease-out;
}
.menu a:active::before {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.menu a:hover::before, a:focus::before {
    transform-origin: left top;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}


.menu.scrolled {
    color: #000;
    background-color: 
}
/* -=-=-=-=-=  END MENU ITEM HOVER ANIMATION   =-=-=-=-=- */
```

**And the JS:**

```
 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop()) {
                  $('nav').addClass('scrolled');
            }

            else {
                  $('nav').removeClass('scrolled');
            }
      })

             $(function () {
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    if ($(this).scrollTop()> 2) {

                        $('.logo img').attr('src', 'res/logos/main.png');

                    }
                    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 2) {

                        $('.logo img').attr('src', 'res/logos/main_light.png');
                    }
                });
            });
```

**And the important HTML:**

```
<header class="index">

                  <nav class="navbar">

                        <div class="logo">
                             <a href="#">
                                    <img class="logoimg" src="res/logos/main_light.png">
                              </a>

                        </div>



                        <div class="menu">
                              <ul>
                                    <li><a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page1.html">Company</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                              </ul>
                        </div>
                  </nav>

            </header>
```

Note that *.scrolled* is the one that changes the navbar once you scrolled. May your road lead you to warm sands!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the transition for the `a` elements twice. First as `.menu a` and then as `nav ul li a`. The nav bar animates when scrolling up, but the transition lasts 0.1s, as declared for the selector `.menu a`.

You can either change `.menu a` to `.menu nav ul li a` or redesign your classes.

For the underline animation, just add the `nav.scrolled` selector to the classes you already have, for instance: `nav.scrolled .menu a::before` and change the background color. You will probably also need to re position the `::before` element.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your tips solved all of my problems. These were simple things but 4 years of not working with CSS anymore have taken their toll.